# Copy and Paste Foreign Characters

Tags: linux, emacs, putty

How do I copy foreign characters (like Chinese, German, etc) from my browser into Putty (Emacs)?

Answer (score 1):

Under Window/Translation, change the "Received data assumed to be in which character set:" drop-down box to UTF-8.